# Converting Ruby timestamp to seconds in Epoch and back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a field in my database that is stored as a timestamp, I need to output this in seconds in EPOCH time.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Supposing your timestamp is a Ruby *Time* object:

```
puts time_stamp.strftime('%s')
puts time_stamp.to_i
timestamp = Time.at(628232400)
```

In case it is a *DateTime* object, you have the *strftime* and *strptime* methods at your disposal.

Comment: I imagine this is a new addition since you wrote this nine years ago, but personally I prefer `tv_sec` (time value in seconds), as it's much clearer about what's happening than `to_i`, which to my eyes is a blind assumption that a time converted to an integer should be seconds since the epoch.

Comment: @JakeRobb it's hardly a _blind assumption_ as it's in the specs (https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Time.html#method-i-to_i),  but I do agree `tv_sec` is a little more descriptive, although the prefix `tv` on itself could be better.

Comment: Yes, it's in the specs, but consider all the programmers you've ever met. How many of them would make the "blind" assumption, and how many would check the spec? My 20+ years of experience across many languages and hundreds of programmers says that a low-single-digit percentage would check the spec.

100% agreed that it's not at all obvious that `tv` stands for time value.

Answer (score 49):

Returns number of seconds since epoch:

```
time = Time.now.to_i
```

Returns second since epoch which includes microseconds:

```
time = Time.now.to_f
```

Comment: This didn't answer my question, I wanted to know how to convert the Ruby Time class to Epoch Unix seconds, not the other way around.

Answer (score 16):

```
Time.now.to_i
```

returns the Epoch. Same goes for:

```
time = Time.now
time.to_i
```